# Проблема с моделью в Yii2

Tags: yii2

Создал свою модель, вызываю ее в другой моделе и получаю ошибку

```
Unable to find 'frontend\models\profile\UploadForm' in file: /home/dev/www/mcs/frontend/models/profile/UploadForm.php. Namespace missing?
```

Чем это может быть вызвано?

Вот что сейчас там (начало):

```
<?
namespace app\models;
namespace frontend\models\profile;

use yii\base\Model;
use yii\web\UploadedFile;

class UploadForm extends Model
{
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Там же написано чем - файл `/home/dev/www/mcs/frontend/models/profile/UploadForm.php` автолоадер нашёл, а в нём не может найти класс \frontend\models\profile\UploadForm . Проверьте имя неймспейса должно быть

```
namespace frontend\models\profile;
```

Проверьте регистр букв в названии класса - должен быть `class UploadForm`

Comment: не помогло, в вопросе дополнил кодом

Comment: @Diefair не может быть два объявления namespace - удалите `namespace app\models` . Если вам нужно использовать этот неймспейс - то `use app\models` и обязательно после строчки `namespace app\models`

Comment: удалил сроку `namespace app\models` - проблема осталась

Comment: @Diefair тогда файл не найден. Проверьте что по пути `/home/dev/www/mcs/frontend/models/profile/UploadForm.php` точно он находится. Проверьте что файл инклюдится добавив в начало файла `var_dump(123); die();` (этож вообще классическая отладка PHP) , попробуйте `<?` заменить на `<?php`.

Comment: такая тупая ошибка. надо было просто вместо `<?` написать `<?php`. спасибо вам

Comment: @Diefair незачто. Но это значит настройки PHP надо подправить - он должен понимать тег <? а также `<?=$some?>` . Опция short_open_tag=On . Такие теги просто удобнее и читаемее)

Comment: @ГончаровАлександр  `<?=$some?>` никак не связан с `short_open_tag` с версии 5.4...... Но это (short_open_tag), в любом случае, не желательно и считается устаревшим. И это может привести к плачевным результатам при разработке приложений или библиотек, предназначенных для распространения или при публикации на серверы, которые вами не контролируются, поскольку сокращённые тэги могут не поддерживаться на целевом сервере. Пролетите как фанера над парижем....А также может быть конфликт с открывающим тэгом XML <?xml. .... Думаю не стоит рекомендовать такие теги